# Missing tabs in the Explain section in pgAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Missing tabs in the Explain section in pgAdmin 4. Unable to view query plan with string. How to return tabs?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJzkb.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the Explain plan for the query:

> To generate the *Explain* or *Explain Analyze* plan of a query, click on *Explain* or *Explain Analyze* button in the toolbar.
>
> More options related to *Explain* and *Explain Analyze* can be selected from the drop down on the right side of *Explain Analyze* button in the toolbar.
>
> [image]
>
> Please note that pgAdmin generates the *Explain [Analyze]* plan in JSON format.
>
> On successful generation of *Explain* plan, it will create three tabs/panels under the Explain panel.

From [pgAdmin 4's documentation of the Explain panel](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/query_tool.html#explain-panel)

Comment: added a screenshot. Tabs are not visible to me

Comment: What version of pgAdmin 4 are you using? The Query Plan Analyser was added with [Issue #4778](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/4778) as part of [v4.14](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/release_notes_4_14.html).